# Calculate percentage between dynamic number of inputfields

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller

I need to display the percentage each input value contains out of the full dataset.

So if the user inputs 3, 2 and 1. The "percent" inputfield should show "50, 30 and 20"

The thing is, i dont know how many inputs the form will get. It could be from 1 to any number.

The source html code is created by a partial view i created. The output is:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th><th>Distributiob key</th><th>Percent</th>
    </tr>

<tr>
    <td>
        House 1
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" size="5" value="0" id="LightPhysicalEntities_0__DistributionKey" name="LightPhysicalEntities[0].DistributionKey" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"  size="5" id="LightPhysicalEntities_0__Percent" readonly=readonly />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        House 2
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" size="5" value="0" id="LightPhysicalEntities_1__DistributionKey" name="LightPhysicalEntities[1].DistributionKey" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"  size="5" id="LightPhysicalEntities_1__Percent" readonly=readonly />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        House 3
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" size="5" value="0" id="LightPhysicalEntities_2__DistributionKey" name="LightPhysicalEntities[2].DistributionKey" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text"  size="5" id="LightPhysicalEntities_2__Percent" readonly=readonly />
    </td>
</tr>
```

First field in the table is the title or name. Second is where the user punches in distribution number. Third is the readonly field with the calculated percentage.

The calculation should be done in javascript, but i cant quite crack the nut on how to get started, getting the inputs and setting the outputs.

Comment: *...if the user inputs 3, 2 and 1. The "percent" inputfield should show "50, 30 and 20"*, based on what?

Comment: @mfiis Along with David - How is those values calculated?

Comment: Ah sorry, i missed that part. 3+2+1 = 6. 3 is 50% of 6. 2 is 30% of 6 and 1 is 20% of 6.
Makes sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A function like this should help (this will round down the percentages- replace the `Math.floor` if you want to handle differently):

```
function calcPcts() {
    var distributions = $("[id$=DistributionKey]");

    // Get the base first
    var base = 0;
    distributions.each(function () {
        base += window.parseInt($(this).val(), 10);
    });

    // Now calculate the percentages of the individual ones
    distributions.each(function () {
        var input = $(this),
            val = window.parseInt($(this).val(), 10),
            pct = (val === 0) ? val : Math.floor((val / base) * 100);
        $("#" + input.attr("id").replace("DistributionKey", "Percent")).val(pct);
    });
}
```

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you. What i came up with myself was this: http://pastebin.com/0UjZM97L but i didnt get time to make it work.

Could you explain what you do on the "last" line of your function? Im not quite sure whats going on there.

Comment: Glad that helped :-)  What it does is select the percent `input` for the current distribution key `input` that it's working with, e.g. for `"LightPhysicalEntities_0__DistributionKey"` it replaces the `"DistributionKey"` with `"Percent"` to arrive at `"LightPhysicalEntities_0__Percent"`. It then uses this in conjunction with `"#"` to select by ID. Once its got the element it sets its `value` attribute (via `val()`) to the percentage it calculated above.

Answer (score 2):

If you add a class to the input fields you can use jQuery to get the number of items with that class.  Then you can get the values and perform your calculations.

Here is an example:

```
var inputCount = $(".inputfield").length;

$("input[type='text']").change(function() {
    var total = GetTotal();
    for (i = 0; i < inputCount; i++) {
        var inputValue = $('#LightPhysicalEntities_' + i + '__DistributionKey').val();
        if (total != 0) {
            var percent = inputValue / total;
            $('#LightPhysicalEntities_' + i + '__Percent').val(percent);
        }
    }
});

function GetTotal() {
    var total = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < inputCount; i++) {
        var inputValue = $('#LightPhysicalEntities_' + i + '__DistributionKey').val();
        total += parseInt(inputValue);
    }
    return total;
}
```

Here is an example of the script working: http://jsfiddle.net/ZWuQr/